# TabActivity with Custom Title giving NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, xamarin.android, android-tabactivity, custom-titlebar

I have a launcher activity which contains two tabs which corresponds to two separate activities `HeatMap` and `LiveMkt`.

As I read somewhere one can not use following statement in child activities:

```
Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle);
```

So I tried following....

`OnCreate()` of Launcher activity contains :

```
base.OnCreate (bundle);
Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle);
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.TabView);
//Code to create tabs which points to two activities `HeatMap` and `LiveMkt`
```

---

`OnCreate()` of `LiveMkt` contains :

```
base.OnCreate (bundle);
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LiveMkt);
Window.SetFeatureInt(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle,Resource.Layout.TitleBar);
edsearch = (EditText) FindViewById(Resource.Id.edsearch);       
_autoSearchBox = new AutoSearchBox();                       
_autoSearchBox.LoadSearchBox(this,edsearch,lsym);
```

---

where `AutoSearchBox` class has `LoadSearchBox()` which contains

```
public void LoadSearchBox(Activity activity,EditText edsearch,ListView lsym)
{
    edsearch.TextChanged+= delegate 
    {//Something
     }
}
```

---

But when I debugged this, I get `NullPointerException` in `LoadSearchBox()` for `edsearch` and `lsym` even though I have these two elements in `LiveMkt` and passing them to `LoadSearchBox()`.

*`LiveMkt.xml`* contains `ListView` *lsym* and *`TitleBar.xml`* contains `EditText` *edsearch*.

**StackTrace:**

```
Exception Details : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

at AutoSearchBox.LoadSearchBox (Android.App.Activity activity, Android.Widget.EditText edsearch, Android.Widget.ListView lsym)
```

As I'm new to *Mono Android*, any help appreciated.

Comment: Let me rephrase. Please post the entire stacktrace.

Comment: Apologies for my assumption. I'm just used to seeing larger traces.

Comment: Please post your `LiveMkt.xml`

Comment: Aah! You see `FindViewById()` is a Activity method and since `LiveMkt.xml` doesn't contain the `EditText` (as per your comment above), it will return null as it will only try to find view with id `edsearch` in `LiveMkt.xml`. What you need is to figure out how to attach eventhandlers to custom window title views (which is not a part of your activity).

Comment: I got(and somewhere had an idea)  the 1st part u said. But here comes the catch as I'm not able to crack the 2nd part of the suggestion...

Comment: I'm not using `Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.CustomTitle);` in `LiveMkt.cs` but in main activity i.e. `TabControl.cs`. In other app, where I had not used `TabActivity`, this code works fine with the inclusion of above statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that `edsearch` is not null? The [`FindViewById`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=M%3aAndroid.App.Activity.FindViewById#) method returns null if it couldn't find the view, so it's possible that's what's happening for you.

Comment: It is null after the statement `edsearch = (EditText) FindViewById(Resource.Id.edsearch);` in `OnCreate()` of `LiveMkt`. But I'm not getting why it is null even though I have a `TitleBar.xml` and `edsearch` within that..